# How to use free particles available in the unity store after importing?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, particle-system

I wanted some particle textures for my particle system. I looked up in the unity store and there were some free ones, so I imported them. But when I go inside their textures folder, the textures are full block like images and not like the single transparent texture.

I researched before asking this question but couldn't find anything related to it. My scene is bright so I can't use black background block like textures.

Do I need to edit them further like cropping and removing background? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this two ways.

(1) Can you try it by creating new material. Just assign a material to the image you want to use.

To create a material==> **Assets -> Create -> Material**
give name it, adjust it.

"Create a new material and the apply the texture by clicking the blank box next to albido, then selecting the desired texture."[from here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/974274/hownto-apply-textures-to-materials-in-unity-5.html)

done! Assign it to particle system.

(2) Just assign your texture to particle system. In particle import setting try **Alpha Is Transparent** (In Inspector) checked/unchecked.